# External JSON File - IONIC

Tags: json, ionic-framework

I use the Tab Template, with list of chats and chats detail. I've put the data into a json file, and add it like this in my code : $http.get("http://abcd/Chats.json").
The data are showing on the List of Chats, but it doesn't work on the Detail Page.
I've tested a lot of solution, but I'm still getting an error...

Here is my code:

```
SERVICE
angular.module('starter.services', [])

 .factory('Chats', function($http) {
// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

return {
getChats: function() {
 return $http.get("http://abcd/Chats.json").success(function(response){
chats=response;
return chats;
  });
 },

get: function(chatId) {
for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
  return chats[i];
  }
 }
 return null;
}
};
 });
```

CONTROLLER

```
 .controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
 Chats.getChats().success(function(response){
 $scope.chats =response;
  });
  })

 .controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
$scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
  } )
```

My error is: cannot read property of chat undefined..
Any help please?

Comment: there's a missing information

Comment: Yes, I think so too, but I can't find from where?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `chats` as a var inside your factory.

```
 .factory('Chats', function($http) {
  var chats;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, i've this error: "Cannot read property "lenght" of undefined". The Tab-chat page displays well, with data+photo, but I still can't access the Detail Page..

Comment: Are you sure, that `chats` is set properly inside `getChats()` **before** you call `get()`? Add some console output for further information. By the way it makes no sense to returns a variable inside a promise function.

Comment: You mean like this ? I see well the object and array in the Console. `.factory('Chats', function($http) {
var chats;
  return {
    getChats: function() {
      return $http.get("http://abcd/chats.json").success(function(response){
        chats = response ;
        console.log(chats);
      });
    },
    get: function(chatId) {
        for (i=0;i< chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
        return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

  }
})`